# Asp.net Bart chart drill down on Pop Up window only

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have problem to do bar chart drill down on pop up window,
without refreshing whole page only drill down on popup.

Can anybody please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use plugin for doing so.... Have a look at jquery [Plugin](http://canvasjs.com/html5-javascript-bar-chart/). You can load it as per the event you want onload or on any click event on pop up window as per your requirement. I would also suggest to check out **Highcharts** [here](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-basic)